# Set enum value via dropdown list select (ddl)

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

There are three files:
index.aspx

serverInfo.cs

setup.aspx.vb

My enum is in:

```
---------------
//Class:serverInfo.cs
---------------
public enum ServerVersion
    {
        Exchange2007SP1 = 0,
        Exchange2011 = 1,
    } 

 // <summary>
    /// Creates a new Service Provider for a specific Server version
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverVersion">Version of the Exchange Server</param>
    public ExchangeServiceProvider(ExchangeServerVersion serverVersion)
    {
        this._service = new ExchangeService((ExchangeVersion)serverVersion);
    }

---------------
//Class:setup.aspx.vb
---------------
Private Sub manualConnect()
    Dim accNameM As String = txtAccName2.Text
    Dim passM As String = txtPass2.Text
    Dim exVer As String = ddlExVersion.SelectedValue
    Dim servURL As String = txtURL.Text
    '----------------------------------'

    conToExchange = New ymp.Utility.Services.Exchange.ExchangeServiceProvider()
    conToExchange.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(accNameM, passM)
    '----------------------------------'

    'FOR MANUAL CONNECTION
    conToExchange.Connect(servURL)
    conToExchange.Connect = [Enum].Parse(exVer)
    '---------------------
    Dim connected As Integer = conToExchange.Connect(servURL)
    '--------------------------------------------------

   'CHECK CONNECTION
    conToExchange.Connect(exVer)


    'TRY TO CONNECT TO EXCHANGE USING AUTODISCOVER,ELSE COULD NOT CONNECT
    If connected Then
        'GO TO SUCCESS PAGE
        phManualSetup.Visible = False
        phSuccess.Visible = True
    Else
        phError.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub


-------------
//Markup:index.aspx
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExVersion" runat="server">

<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Ex2010SP1">Exchange 2010 SP1</asp:ListItem>

    <asp:ListItem Value="Ex2011">Exchange 2011</asp:ListItem>



</asp:DropDownList><span></span>
```

What I want to do:

See which version is selected via dropdown list, compare this to the value in the enum store in var and add to my connection check.

Any help or suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Thanks

Comment: You want to path either 0 or 1 into the conToExchange.Connect() method? Argument type is string/integer?

Comment: Yes I want either 0 or 1. Argument type for .Connect is of type .NET microsoft object.

Comment: In this case you can cast ddlExVersion.SelectedValue to integer using Int32.TryParse method (I believe ddlExVersion.SelectedValue contains numeric values)

Comment: I dont think you understood my question. I need to see which version is selected via dropdown list, compare this to the value in the enum store in a new variable and add to my connection check.

Comment: The dropdown list has string values. Hope that helps! Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Each DropDowwnListItem has both Value and Text proeprties, so Value represents "Exchange2007SP1" or "0"?

Comment: Please try to answer the question, thanks!

Comment: answer to my question first because your original question is not pretty clear, so so Value of DropDownList Item represents "Exchange2007SP1" or "0"?

Comment: Value of DropDownList Item represents: Exchange2007SP1.

Comment: Remember there are two different files here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly you need to see if the selected value is a valid/defined enum value, you can do something like this. Place this method in the serverInfo.cs.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the Enum Value based on String provided
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int? GetEnumValue(string value)
{
   ServerVersion newEnumVar;
   bool parsed = Enum.TryParse<ServerVersion>(value, out newEnumVar);

   if (parsed)
   {
       return Convert.ToInt32(newEnumVar);
   }

   return null;
 }
```

and in setup.aspx.vb

```
Dim enumValue as Nullable(Of Integer)
enumValue = conToExchange.GetEnumValue(ddlExVersion.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is off ServerVersion enum type but as you can see they are defined in different files. So please change you answer to suit this. Also yes, I need an enum integer back which matches what was selected client side. Is that clearer? Thanks

Comment: That is not going to work. I don't need code for client side which is asp. Plus this code is not VB .NET. Plus I cannot place code where the enum is defined, I need to call the enum function which is serverInfo.cs, inside and from the file, setup.aspx.vb. Thanks

Comment: What you provided only compares what is selected against what is in the enum. That is fine. But I need it to compare the selected value with a value from enum, then if the selected value matches what is available in the enum then store this in a new variable. Hope that helps buddy

Comment: Plus no need to store what is selected in an enum when I am trying to compare what is selected with a value from the enum.